# gridsim-Exception in thread "router2" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm working on gridsim Min-Min project for workflow in Java Netbeans,i have 3 entities:user,broker and GridResources.
user send application with form of workfllow to broker
broker send gridlets to GridResource;
i implement the network topology for this entities with helping of example "auction" in example folder of Gridsim's pakage.
when run my programe,sometime its run without error and every thing is ok,
but after 3 run or some time after 8 run its failed with error and stop.
i checked network topology with another example but the logic of my programe is ok but im confiusing with this,i searched but not found anything.
anyone help me?

```
Exception in thread "router1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.dequeue(Unknown Source)
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.processInternalEvent(Unknown `enter code here`Source)
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at gridsim.net.Router.body(Unknown Source)
at eduni.simjava.Sim_entity.run(Sim_entity.java:605)
Exception in thread "router2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.dequeue(Unknown Source)
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.processInternalEvent(Unknown Source)
at gridsim.net.RIPRouter.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at gridsim.net.Router.body(Unknown Source)
at eduni.simjava.Sim_entity.run(Sim_entity.java:605)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code for the `Sim_entity` class?

Comment: Tanx, the sim_entity is not my class, i am using the liberary  of                   import eduni.simjava.*; in my classes for the send events from user class to broker class or for broker class to receive event of user class. the linke below is for information about this liberary and methods. http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/simjava/simjava-1.2/doc/eduni.simjava.Sim_entity.html